# Determine the ray pair at the origin of a vein in the Mandelbrot set.

Tags: complex-dynamics

In a paper I found a description of subsets of the Mandelbrot set called veins (these are also described in earlier papers by other authors, for example Chapters 20-22 of the [Orsay Notes](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehubbard/OrsayEnglish.pdf) by Adrien Douady and John H. Hubbard):

> Given  a  dyadic  number $θ ∈ S^1=\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$, we define its complexity as $‖θ‖:= \min\left\{k≥0:D^k(θ) = 0 \mod 1\right\}$. Of  course,  if $θ = p/2^q$ with $p$ odd, then $‖θ‖=q$.   Given  an  interval  $(θ_−,θ_+)$  with $θ_−< θ_+$, we define its pseudocenter $θ_0$ to be the dyadic rational of lowest complexity inside the interval $(θ_−,θ_+)$.  A pair of elements $(θ_−,θ_+)$ is a ray pair if the two external rays of angle $θ_−$ and $θ_+$ combinatorially land at the same parameter on the boundary of the Mandelbrot set.
>
> **Definition 6** Given a dyadic rational number $θ_0$,  we define the *combinatorial vein* of $θ_0$ as the set of ray pairs $(θ_1,θ_2)$ such that:
>
> 1. $θ_0$ is the pseudocenter of $(θ_1,θ_2)$;
> 2. $N(θ_0) = N(θ_1)$.
>
> --
> *Generalizations of Douady's magic formula* Adam Epstein, Giulio Tiozzo https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.03796

Here $D(\theta)$ is the angle doubling map and $N(\theta)$ counts the number of ends of the Hubbard tree for $\theta$.

I can draw Hubbard trees implicitly given preperiodic rational $\theta$ (the Julia sets are dendrites, and neighbourhoods of pixels whose dynamic angles surround a ray landing on one of the marked points (preperiodic critical orbit) of the Hubbard tree are included into the drawn tree).

[image: a Hubbard tree in a dendrite Julia set]

But if I apply this algorithm naively to the Mandelbrot set in an attempt to draw the vein from $\theta_0$, I will miss the second condition and extend the vein too far (the paper has some examples).

Counting the ends of a Hubbard is presumably possible using symbolics of pairs of dynamic rays landing on marked points, but this requires knowing the external angle and I have an arbitrary $c$ in the Mandelbrot set.  I could trace the external parameter rays landing near $c$ to find angles, and if I knew the ray pair at the origin of the vein (the widest ray pair satisfying the conditions) I could use this to prune the results of the naive algorithm (mark the pixel only if both in the extended wrong "vein" and the angle is inside this interval).

[image: Vein for 3/16 with origin (39/224, 43/224)]

So (at least) two methods for solving the problem, but maybe there's a still-better alternative?

**Question: determine the ray pair at the origin of a vein given $\theta_0$.**